# can Verizon wireless see Web traffic when I'm tethering to my pc which is running tor browser?

Tags: anonymity

I use my Verizon wireless phone and a third party app to tether to my home network. When I use tor browser on my pc can Verizon see or read the Web traffic?

The way I have it set up is, I use my third party app to tether, via USB, my phone to a raspberry pi which acts as a wireless router for my home network, then I connect to the wireless network on my pc and run tor browser on the pc.

So if I went to, let's say facebook.com, while running tor browser could Verizon wireless (or anybody else) see and read any Web traffic? Also, if I went to, let's say blahblah.onion, could they see and read any traffic? As well, can the destination website tell where the connection originates from?

I'm just curious how anonymous using tor browser truly makes me when using my Verizon wireless connection. I assume Verizon keeps a record of data transmitted, but can they or anybody else see where I'm connecting to and can the destination tell where I'm connecting from when using tor browser on my pc, in the network configuration I have set up?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is designed so that only you and the server you're connecting to can see you information, it doesn't matter how you are connected. The only thing Verizon Wireless will see is a bunch of encrypted data being sent to a Tor guard relay.

The destination website can only tell where the connection came from, but not necessarily where it originated. The website will just see data coming from a Tor exit relay, and the exit relay itself can only be tracked back to a middle relay.

If the original internet traffic is NOT encrypted (e.g. using unsecured HTTP websites) then there is a chance that 3rd parties can interfere with it, but they will still only be able to trace it back to the exit relay.

Comment: one addition: in this particular case an ISP will be possibly able to detect that it is not just your phone itself using a mobile internet link.